Understanding the Implications of Layer 2 Solutions on Ethereum's Scalability: Time to Finality Considerations
Certain Layer 2 solutions, such as Optimistic Rollups and ZK Rollups, aim to address Ethereum's scalability challenges. While they are expected to significantly increase transactions per second (TPS), I am particularly interested in their Time to Finality (TTF).
Despite processing transactions on Layer 2, they still require submission to the Ethereum network and inclusion in a block to finalize transactions on Layer 2. If this holds true, their TTF must be equal to or longer than Ethereum's, potentially resulting in poorer performance in scenarios where TTF is critical.
Is my understanding accurate? If so, it suggests that all Layer 2 solutions encounter significant TTF limitations, prompting the necessity for additional Layer 1 solutions such as Solana to address this concern.
My questions are:

Is my reasoning above correct?
Are there other ways to mitigate the TTF issue on Layer 2?

